# Django-debug-toolbar-line-profiler shows only a single line of output, no content

Tags: python, django, profiling, raspberry-pi, django-debug-toolbar

I have a Raspberry Pi sitting in a remote location.  It is hooked up to a small homemade circuit and a temperature probe.  I've set up the Raspberry Pi to do a few things:

- Run `cron` jobs every hour to take a temperature reading and store it locally to a sqlite database
- Run an Nginx web server
- Run a uwsgi application server
- Serve a simple Django app

In that Django app, I have a simple view that does the following:

1. Hit the DB to get the last 300 temperature recordings
2. Put those into a Pandas `DataFrame`
3. Use Matplotlib to produce a nice SVG graph of the recent temperature history
4. Fill out a simple template which displays the SVG and also a small HTML table of the recent temperature readings.

Rendering this view takes ~30 seconds.  A very long time.  So I wanted to see what was taking so long.  My guess is that it's all the work related to generating the graphics.  But to find out, I wanted to do some profiling.

I installed `django-debug-toolbar` and also `django-debug-toolbar-line-profiler` using pip.

I have configured them according to the docs as best I understood.  In particular, I've set:

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PATCH_SETTINGS = False

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = (
    'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',

    'debug_toolbar_line_profiler.panel.ProfilingPanel',
)
```

In addition, `INTERNAL_IPS` is also set properly.

I have built my view using class-based views.  It looks like this:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from XXXX.models import TempReading, TempSeries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
import seaborn as sbn
import StringIO

class TestView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'XXXX/test.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        upstairs = TempSeries.objects.get(name='Upstairs')
        upstairstemps = upstairs.tempreading_set.all().order_by('-timestamp')[:300]

        frame = pd.DataFrame(list(upstairstemps.values()))
        frame.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

        # matplotlib.rcParams['svg.fonttype'] = 'none'

        fig = Figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        frame['value'].plot(ax=ax)
        ax.get_xaxis().grid(color='w', linewidth=1)
        ax.get_yaxis().grid(color='w', linewidth=1)

        fig.set(facecolor='w')
        canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)

        imgdata = StringIO.StringIO()
        canvas.print_svg(imgdata)

        imgstr = imgdata.getvalue()

        context = super(TestView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['svgtext'] = imgstr
        context['htmltable'] = frame[:5].to_html()

        return context
```

The code I am most interested in profiling is `get_context_data`.

When I load the page, the debug-toolbar does in fact show up.  And the profiling panel is shown.  But all I see is:

```
{method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Here's a screenshot of the page as it first loads:
[image]

And here's how it looks on the profiling page:
[image]

It doesn't seem like it's doing any "line-profiling" at all!  I was expecting to see timed results for every line within my class-based view.  In particular, for each line within the `get_context_data` function.  What's going on?  Any help much appreciated.

---

**Edit on 4/2**

Just as a test, I wrote up a dummy view that *does not* use class-based views.  And this seems to work just fine.  Here's the new non-class-based-view:

```
def testview2(request):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(10), 'b': np.random.randn(10)})
    htmltable = df.to_html()
    context = {}
    context['htmltable'] = htmltable

    return render(request, 'XXXX/test2.html', context)
```

And that produces the following result in the profiling pane:
[image]

So that seems to be working fine.  Is there some subtlety I'm missing about how `debug-toolbar-line-profiler` works with class-based views?  In the docs, it suggests it will profile any method on the class that does not start with an underscore.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: What's your working environment? windows, Linux/UNIX or mac?

Comment: It's deployed on a Raspberry Pi

Comment: If there is any additional info that would be helpful, please let me know.

Comment: This is just a guess, but the `disable` call on an object called `Profiler` sure looks like something went wrong as the profiler tried to attach to the code, so it disabled itself before the code ran, and that's all you're seeing in the profile. If there is a log to check where more information might be sent, go check that!

Comment: A bit new to profiling in this context.  Any thoughts on where such a log might be?

Comment: So am I, but I'd start with the django logs.  The docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/

Comment: BTW, most things that run slowly on RP trace to "disk" IO.  The SD card interface is limited, and all SD cards are _not_ created equal.  Check out http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12191/what-speed-of-sd-card-is-better.

Comment: Fair point.  I understand that would be a good strategy to improve performance.  For now, though, I mostly just want to the profiler up and running for class-based-views.

Comment: I have the exact same problem - some views work fine and others don't.  They are all the same basic structure.  Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: put the django_toolbar middleware at the end , i.e after all other middle ware

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this happening when I decorated my views with `@csrf_exempt`; once removed the profiler worked fine.

Not sure why it causes the issue but that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are hosting this on some chip, I would strongly recommend you keep the server side as simple as possible and move the complicated logic handling to client side.

yeah, trust JS can do as much as python. and it will not be on your server. All those graphics plotting, even template rendering, you should move it to client side. this will definitely eliminate the page serving time for a chip-like device.

As for the debugging, why don't you debug it on real PC and then move it to Ras-Pi. you might add some simple logging logic  to bench mark the sections you want to examine.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response.  Your note about moving processing to the client side to improve performance is reasonable.  But this isn't really about improving performance...it's about getting the benchmarking tool to work "as advertised".  Any thoughts on why the profiler isn't working?